# Kotlin won't allow me to set an optional field to null

Tags: kotlin

[*I posted this question previously, but the Stackoverflow bot closed it because it apparently couldn't figure out that I was looking for an answer to fix an error I am getting, so I reworded it*]

I am trying to set an optional field to null.

```
var displayInfoForFaction: Faction? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

ItemInfoIcon(
    faction,
    displayInfoForFaction?.name,
    onClickFunc = {
        displayInfoForFaction = faction
        faction.showInfo = true
    },
    onDismissFunc = {
        // TODO - don't know what is going on here - NPE for null cast is happening on the next statement
        displayInfoForFaction = null
        faction.showInfo = false
    },
)
```

But when I run the above code, I am getting the following error:

```
NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
```

I’ve seen a lot of hits when searching on this error, but they’re all because people are trying to set a non-optional field to null. But as you can see above, the field I am trying to set *is* optional. I’m assuming that maybe the `remember` is part of the problem, but I’m not sure how to resolve this.

Here is the code that is using the field:

```
@Composable
fun ItemInfoIcon(
    cardItem: CardItem,
    currentName: String?,
    onClickFunc: () -> Unit,
    onDismissFunc: () -> Unit,
) {
    val itemDescription = StringBuilder(cardItem.description!!)
        .appendLine().appendLine()
    if (cardItem.game != null) {
        itemDescription.append(
            "${ApplicationText.getAppText(MODULE_NAME, "fromGame")}${cardItem.game}"
        )
    }
    val cardItemCount = cardItem.count
    if (cardItemCount != null && cardItemCount > 0) {
        itemDescription.appendLine()
            .append(
                "${ApplicationText.getAppText(MODULE_NAME, "numberOfCards")}$cardItemCount"
            )
    }
    Box(
        Modifier.clickable(
            onClick =
            { onClickFunc() }
        )
    ) {

        if (cardItem.name == currentName && cardItem.showInfo) {
            ItemInfoDialog(
                name = cardItem.name,
                description = itemDescription.toString(),
            ) {
                onDismissFunc()
            }
        }

        Icon(
            Icons.Rounded.Info,
            contentDescription = "Display info about ${cardItem::class.simpleName}",
        )
    }
}
```